# Refresh datatable serverside set to false datatable 1.8.1

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Im trying to refresh the datable with the serverside process is false.
but it says `oTable.draw()` is not a function. i echoed my data in the table using PHP. I am using datatable 1.8.1. Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks

```
  oTable = jQuery("#requestt").dataTable( {
                "aaSorting": [],
                "aoColumns": [
                                { "bSearchable": true ,"bSortable": true},
                                { "bSearchable": true ,"bSortable": true},
                                { "bSearchable": true ,"bSortable": true},
                                { "bSearchable": true ,"bSortable": true},
                                { "bSearchable": true ,"bSortable": true},
                                { "bSearchable": true ,"bSortable": true},
                                { "bSearchable": false , "bSortable": false,"sWidth":"10%"},
                                { "bSearchable": false , "bSortable": false,"sWidth":"10%"}
                            ]

            } );

function deleteBuildRequest(reqId){
          $.post("/admin/deletebuildRequest",
            {
             rid:reqId
            },
            function(data){
                oTable.draw();
              }
            );
      }

<table id="requestt" class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Req Id</th>
          <th>Domain</th>
          <th>Framework</th>
          <th>Server</th>
          <th>Requested By</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>
            <label><input class="del-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkAll"> Select All</label>
            <div>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-default delete-btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</a>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php if ($requests->num_rows() > 0):?>
           <?php foreach ($requests->result() as $row):?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->ReqId?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->DomainName?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->FrameworkName?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->name?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->FirstName." ".$row->LastName?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("m/d/y g:i A", strtotime( $row->DateRequested));?></td>
                <td>
                <?php if ($this->members->IsAdmin($this->session->userdata('userid'))===true):?>
                   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="requestDelete" id="delete_<?php echo $row->ReqId ?>" title="delete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                   &nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="requestSwitch" id="switch_<?php echo $row->ReqId ?>" title="switch">Approve Switch</i></a>
                 <?php endif;?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="del-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row->ReqId?>"> 
                </td>
              </tr>
           <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endif?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the place of

```
oTable = jQuery("#requestt").dataTable( {
```

use this

```
oTable = jQuery("#requestt").DataTable( {
```

It will fix your problem..

and if you are facing any problem after that

cover it with `document.ready()`